# How to remove an attribute from list of json object in mongo shell?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

suppose I have a json object as below:

```
{
  "_id" : some mongo generated id,
  "name" : "NEW NODE",
  "example_list" : [{
     "_id" : "1.3.12.2.1107.5.99.3.30000008061114424970500000589",
     "Index" : 0,
     "Type" : "Study"
     }, {
      "_id" : "cc7e1966-e885-4a9a-8077-c3489118938d",
      "Index" : 1,
      "Type" : "TestCase"
    }]
}
```

now I want to delete `"Type"` from `"example_list"` in `mongo shell`.

Is there any way to do it in mongo shell?

I have found some scripts but its not working on mongo shell I am more inclined on doing this on mongo shell but other ways are also fine.

Comment: How many records you want to update? Is there any specific condition you need to check before removing the field?

Comment: maybe 10-20 records. No there is no check for removing the field. I just have to remove it.